# How can I animate the start of setting an adapter to a gridview?

Tags: android, animation, gridview, adapter

In my android app I am using a gridview. Now I would like to animate it, so that when I set the adapter to the gridview I get some kind of fade in transition.

Ideally, what I am looking for is an effect similar to the one used in this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en. There I mean the effect when you click on a folder.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Shall I use NineOldAndroids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use/integrate this

https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView

The Above link is for GridView and ListView

also you can use from these also

https://github.com/Trinea/android-open-project/tree/master/English%20Version